# Execute click function within setTimeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I've got the following function to animate between a couple of divs:

```
   jQuery('.nav').click(
        function hideShow () { 
            var targ  = jQuery(this)[0].className.split(' ')[1];
            jQuery('.slide.' +targ).addClass('active').animate({opacity:1});
            jQuery('.slide:not(.active)').animate({opacity:0});

            if(jQuery('.slide').css('opacity') == 0) {
               jQuery('.slide').removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    );
```

And I would like to run it automatically using:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    triggerClick('.nav', 0),
    hideShow();
}, 5000);

function triggerClick(selector, index) {
    var slideNav= jQuery(selector);
    var mod = index++ % slideNav.length;
    jQuery(slideNav[mod]).trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function() {
        triggerClick(selector, index);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Basically I would like to run my hideshow function every 5 seconds to reset the opacity om my slider item but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: The slider is working, but the trigger function doesn't reset 'active' class and opacity value.

Comment: It would be easy to see your codes in action. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I did a quick mock up [link]http://jsfiddle.net/vrFVu/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by first removing the active in my click function:

```
   jQuery('.nav').click(
        function () { 
            var targ  = jQuery(this)[0].className.split(' ')[1];
            jQuery('.slide').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('.slide.' +targ).addClass('active').animate({opacity:1});
            jQuery('.slide:not(.active)').animate({opacity:0});

            if(jQuery('.slide').css('opacity') == 0) {
               jQuery('.slide').removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    );
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vrFVu/2/